# how to deactivate Ctrl+B in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, tmux

I'd like to use tmux in the Sagemaker's terminal and need a default tmux "ctrl+b" combination for that, which is also occupied by Sagemaker to toggle the left sidebar.

I want to deactivate CTRL + B in Sagemaker.

Changing tmux shortcuts is not an option here, but capitulation.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker/Studio UI is built on JupyterLab. So, you can disable Jupyter lab keyboard shortcuts (Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor). Take a look at https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6249 for reference.

Comment: I have tried to delete the `ctrl + b` shortcut on Jupyter Notebook AWS Sagemaker, but it seems cannot delete/edit the default shortcut. This is so annoying when I need to use the tmux too on Sagemaker. Can you show me how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents to the other answer:
You open `Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor`, click `JSON Settings Editor` at the top right corner.
Then there is a **System Defaults** and a **User preferences** pane.

If the shortcut is already present on the User preferences pane, add the `"disabled": "true"` keyword to it. If it is not, then we have to copy it from the System defaults and then do the same. For the `ctrl + b` shortcut the config is:

```
        {
            "args": {},
            "command": "application:toggle-left-area",
            "keys": [
                "Accel B"
            ],
            "disabled": "true",
            "selector": "body"
        }
```